# How to upload and start application on started VM in azure?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud

I can use management API to [deploy\destroy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722415.aspx#bk_createres) a VM on Azure. Yet I need to be able to upload and start an application in it. How can I perform such operation using Azure C# Management APIs?

Comment: What type of application do you want to start? My point is, if you want to start a web app or windows service - I would suggest that you look into the platform offerings, that makes your life a lot easier.

Comment: You should consider using ARM template with custom script extension. For uploading data, you can consider attaching a data disk to you VM, or you can specify customData inside osProfile. It's encoded with base64. See these 2 templates, [custom script extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-customscript-extension-azure-storage-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.json) and [custom data](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-customdata/azuredeploy.json)